# Embedding a Collection View inside a Container View - extra white-space at top

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I have an app that uses a Nav Contoller as it's initial VC, which then has a root UIViewContoller that contains a UIView at the top half, and a UIContainerView at the bottom.  In the UIContanerView, I'm embedding a working UICollectionView that contains image buttons that segue to detail views.

**The problem is that white space now shows up at the top of the UICollectionView.**  Given this is around 64 pixels high, it appears to be a ghosting of a Nav Bar 44px + Status Bar 20px = 64.

[image: Extra space of around 64px in my UICollectionView (I set it gray)]

And if I scroll up everything looks fine and works as expected, and it also allows me to show you what I expected the layout to look like upon launch:

[image: What I expected the launch layout to look like]

A snippet of my storyboard is below if that helps:

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: It's been a while since I had this problem and I don't exactly remember the resolution :-(.  IIRC The issue is that the container view is inside of a navigation view and the operating system is trying to be very helpful by moving the content down by the height of the navigation view.  If I remember correctly one thing you can check is the container view's "layoutMargins".  I think you'll find the top margin set and you can try to clear that.

Comment: check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786198/uicollectionview-how-can-i-remove-the-space-on-top-first-cells-row

Comment: Thanks, let me to the one line answer: `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Answer (score 10):

yes, that could be because child view controller embedded in container view gets the impression, that it is a direct child of UINavigationController, which in turn make collectionView leave top 64 pt insets.

TO solve this problem,In your child view controller interface builder, unmark adjust scrollView insets

[image: In your child view controller interface builder, unmark adjust scrollView insets]

This should solve your problem

**UPDATE**

As Dan suggested, we can also fix it programatically, by calling

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

in viewDidLoad() of your UIViewController

Comment: That is it, and matches the answer I found from the link @Scott Thompson posted above.  I actually placed the one line in the viewDidLoad() so it would be less "hidden" when I come back months from now... ;o)  `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: It appears that both container controller and child controller has to be unchecked to make it works.

Comment: It is only needed for the controller that contains scrollView in it!