# UICollectionview - removing right padding/margin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to do a slideshow display of items and I have an issue where there is a mysterious padding added to the first cell(on the left side) and last cell(right side) as shown below and demonstrated by the black box

[image]

```
            DataSource datasource = new DataSource(Vcollection, PageControl, this);
            Vcollection.Source = datasource;

            doRefreshList = true;

            Vcollection.CollectionViewLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            {
                ItemSize = Vcollection.Frame.Size,
                HeaderReferenceSize = new CGSize(0, 0),
                SectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero,
                ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal,

                MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0f, // minimum spacing between cells
                MinimumLineSpacing = 0f,
                SectionInsetReference = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutSectionInsetReference.ContentInset,

            };
            Vcollection.ContentInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            Vcollection.ScrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
            Vcollection.ContentOffset = new CGPoint(0f, 0f);
            this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

This is my code where I tried to rectify the issue, but to no avail. How can I remove this padding?

------------------EDIT ---------------------
Replacing the last 4 lines with

```
VehicleCollectionView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -20, 0, 0);
            VehicleCollectionView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.Never;
```

Works, however pagination is still off. attempting to scroll through the collectionview shows huge offsets as shown below where pagination is stuck between 2 items

[image]

Comment: Try to set ContentInset of CollectionView and set AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to false ,refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23786370/8187800.

Comment: Works for the first page, scrolling through rest of the pages shows weird offsets

Comment: What  weird offsets  ? Could you post a basic project for us to test ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewDidLoad()` method you can try two write this code

```
collectionView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets (10, 10, 10, 10);
//collectionView.SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets (20, 20, 20, 20)
```